# Comparable Interface Issue

Tags: java, interface, comparable

Hi I wrote simple code for Comparable interface As below

```
import java.util.*;
class Gaurav123 implements Comparable<Gaurav123>
{
  String title;
  Gaurav123()
  {

  }

  Gaurav123(String title)
  {
    this.title=title;
  }

  public int compareTO(Gaurav123 b)
  {
    return title.compareTo(b.title);
  }
}

public class Gaurav1234
{

  public static void main(String [] args)
  {
    Gaurav123 g1=new Gaurav123("gaurav");
    Gaurav123 g2=new Gaurav123("Surbhi");
    Gaurav123 g3=new Gaurav123("Kailash");
    TreeSet<Gaurav123>ts=new TreeSet<Gaurav123>();
    ts.add(g1);
    ts.add(g2);
    ts.add(g3);
  }
}
```

But I am getting this error

```
C:\Users\gakaushik\Desktop>javac Gaurav1234.java
Gaurav1234.java:2: Gaurav123 is not abstract and does not override abstract meth
od compareTo(Gaurav123) in java.lang.Comparable
class Gaurav123 implements Comparable<Gaurav123>
^
1 error
```

Any Idea what is the issue. I followed all Comparable interface protocols

Answer (score 2):

Java is fully case sensitive... Your method is called

```
compareTO
```

It should be called

```
compareTo
```

However, next time be sure to read the error message carefully, it is usually a good hint what to look at... Another good thing to do before asking a question is to copz and paste the error into any search engine you find (even at Stackoverflow)

Comment: oopss My blunder Thanks a lot...got it

Comment: @user2600324 Everyone makes mistakes :)